# How to read the uploaded document in the same script in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

Anyone know how to open and read the uploaded document in the same script in PHP?

I have a form to upload the word file in **index.php**. Now, I upload the word document. It goes to the file called **upload.php** and upload it successfully. Now i am wondering that **How can write the code for open and read the uploaded file in the same script that means in upload.php**

I am very new to PHP. So, please help me and explain me the flow of process detailed. Thanks in advance.

coding for index.php

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
           HTML Converter
      </title>

   </head>
   <body>      
       <h4>HTML Converter</h4>
       <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">

    Please choose a file: <input name="file" type="file" /><br />

 <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" />
 </form> 
   </body>
</html>
```

coding for upload.php

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      $filedata = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo $filedata

    ;

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents` param path is looking wrong, because you have uploaded file `upload` dir, add dir name

```
$filedata = file_get_contents("./upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: thanks for yoour replies. It works. But i want the content of the file should display as it is in the format. I used content type for docx. but not works. Where do i write the content type in upload.php to display everything in a document

Comment: you should use google doc API.. to show office file/pdf on browser.. for more info and generate embedded code here https://docs.google.com/a/octalsoftware.com/viewer

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. You need to add folder name `upload/` (relative path).

```
$filedata = file_get_contents("upload/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: thanks for yoour replies. It works. But i want the content of the file should display as it is in the format. I used content type for docx. but not works. Where do i write the content type in upload.php to display everything in a document.